# How to draw an empty cell using TDBGrid?

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

I'm trying to display an empty text for a `TDBGrid`'s cell without changing the field's value neither the backcolor of the cell.
I'm not sure it's the right approach but I've tried using the `OnDrawDataCell` event as follows:

```
procedure TMyForm.MyGridDrawDataCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; Field: TField; State: TGridDrawState);
var
    Grid : TDBGrid;
begin
  inherited;
  if(Field.FieldName = 'MYFIELD') then
  begin
    Grid := Sender as TDBGrid;
    Grid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  end;
end;
```

After placing a breakpoint into the event, I've noticed that it's never executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved using `OnDrawColumnCell` event handler instead of the obsolete `OnDrawDataCell`

As [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBGrids_TDBGrid_OnDrawDataCell.html) says:

> Do not write an OnDrawDataCell event handler. OnDrawDataCell is
>   obsolete and included for backward compatibility. Instead, write an
>   OnDrawColumnCell event handler.